# Given a string, find the longest substring with the same number of vowels and consonants?

Tags: java, algorithm, function

> Given a string, find the longest substring with the same number of vowels and consonants.

**CLARIFICATION:** I am unsure, whether we can generate a new string, or the substring has to be part of the original string? So far I have this,

**Code Snippet :**

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string = new String(scanner.next());
    int lengthOfString = string.length();
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int consCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == 'u' || string.charAt(i) == 'e'  || string.charAt(i) == 'i'
                || string.charAt(i) == 'o' || string.charAt(i) == 'a' ) {
            vowelCount++;


        } else {

            consCount++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(vowelCount);
```

**EDIT** I got the count working, but how do I create a substring?

Comment: `Given a string ... find the longest substring` ... so are there two strings in this problem, or only one?

Comment: For finding if a character is a vowel, you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19161184/5743988) for simpler code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm pretty sure there is only 1 string? The task is to find the longest substring where `consonantCount == vowelCount`.

Comment: Is it safe for you to assume all non-vowels are consonants? What if there are spaces, or numbers?

Comment: Your question would be clearer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved in **O(n) time and space** using the "net" values computed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39607701/47984) in combination with the following observation:

- A substring s[i .. j] has the same number of consonants and vowels if and only if net[1 .. i-1] = net[1 .. j], where net[i .. j] is the sum of the "net" values (1 for a vowel, -1 for a consonant) for each character between positions i and j, inclusive.

To see this, observe that the condition that tells us that a substring s[i .. j] is the kind we're looking for is that

```
net[i .. j] = 0.
```

Adding net[1 .. i-1] to both sides of this equation gives

```
net[1 .. i-1] + net[i .. j] = net[1 .. i-1]
```

with the LHS then simplifying to just

```
net[1 .. j] = net[1 .. i-1]
```

### Algorithm

That means that we can create a table containing two entries (first position seen and last position seen) for each possible distinct value that we could get as we calculate a running sum of net values.  This running total could range as low as -n (if every character is a consonant) or as high as n (if every character is a vowel), so there are at most 2n+1 distinct such sums in total, so we'll need that many rows in our table.  We then march through the string from left to right calculating a running total net value, and updating the pair in the table that corresponds to the current running total, noticing whenever this update produces a new, maximum-length substring.  In pseudocode, with zero-based array indices and using separate arrays to hold the elements in each pair:

1. Create 2 arrays of length 2n+1, first[] and last[], initially containing all -2s, except for first[n] which is -1.  (Need to use -2 as a sentinel since -1 is actually a valid value!)
2. Set bestFirst = bestLast = bestLen = -1.
3. Set the running total t = n.  (n "means" 0; using this bias just means we can use the running total directly as a nonnegative-valued index into the arrays without having to repeatedly add an offset to it.)
4. For i from 0 to n-1:

   - If s[i] is a vowel, increment t, otherwise decrement t.
   - If first[t] is -2:

     - Set first[t] = i.
   - Otherwise:

     - Set last[t] = i.
     - If last[t] - first[t] > bestLen:

       - Set bestLen = last[t] - first[t].
       - Set bestFirst = first[t] + 1.
       - Set bestLast = last[t].

A maximum-length range will be returned in (bestFirst, bestLast), or if no such range exists, these variables will both be -1.

I remember seeing this solution, or one very similar to it, somewhere on SO a while back -- if anyone can find it, I'll gladly link to it.

Answer (score 2):

To find the longest substring where the number of consonants and vowels are equal, start finding substrings at the largest length, and steadily decrease the length needed until you find a substring that matches the criteria.

This will allow you to short-circuit the operation.

```
public static String findLongestSubstring(String str) {
    for (int len = str.length(); len >= 2; len--) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - len; i++) {
            String substr = str.substring(i, i + len);
            int vowels = countVowels(substr);
            int consonants = len - vowels;
            if (vowels == consonants) {
                return substr;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

private static int countVowels(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiou]+", "").length(); 
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because you figured out how to loop in such a way to check longest strings _first_, thus eliminating unnecessary work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, though I'm still not super happy with this, because it's O(n^3) just like everyone elses, but maybe someone will think of something less brute-force.

Comment: @4castle, how did you find that it was O(n^3)?

Comment: @YOGIYO `N^2` to iterate over every substring, plus another `O(N)` operation to count vowels and consonants.

Comment: More efficient algorithm for generating all substrings discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560262/generate-all-unique-substrings-for-given-string)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, what is N here?

Comment: @YOGIYO You can think of `N` as the worst-case number of comparison operations having to be done to determine if a character is a vowel. You can read more about Big-O notation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/5743988), and there's plenty of articles online.

Comment: @4castle I found a way to do this in `O(n^2)`, q.v. my updated answer.  It is possible to avoid iterating over each substring to check for vowels, by cleverly keeping a running tally of number of vowels and consonants.

Comment: @4castle, can you help me out in calculating? The first loop has (str.length - 1) rotations. The second loop depends on the first loop, so it goes like: (0), [0, 1], [0, 1, 2] , ... , [0, 1 .., str.length - 2] Thus this is a total of (Second loop only) 1 + 2 + ... + N - 2 = (2N-3)^2/8 -1/8 ~ (2N)^2. If we let N=str.length. In the first loop, we have (N-1) ~ N, thus a total of ~N^3. But then we have to assume that inside both the loops, it is O(1) otherwise we have have > O(N^3)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated version of my original answer which runs in `O(n^2)` time.  It achieves this by employing a trick, namely keeping track of a single variable (called 'net') which tracks the *difference* between the number of vowels and consonants.  When this number is zero, a given substring is balanced.

It takes `O(n^2)` to iterate over every possible substring in the worst case, but it doesn't take any additional time check each substring for strings and vowels, because it keeps the `net` up to date with each new step to choose a substring.  Hence, it reduces the complexity from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)`.

```
public String findLongestSubstring(String input) {
    String longest = "";

    for (int window = inputz.length(); window >=2; --window) {
        String substr = input.substring(0, window);
        String consonants = input.substring(0, window).toLowerCase()
                .replaceAll("[aeiou]", "");
        int vowelCount = input.substring(0, window).length() - consonants.length();
        int consonantCount = consonants.length();

        int net = vowelCount - consonantCount;

        for (int i=window; i <= input.length(); ++i) {
            if (net == 0) {
                longest = input.substring(i-window, i);
                return longest;
            }

            // no-op for last window
            if (i == input.length()) break;

            // update tally by removing high character
            if ("aeiou".indexOf(input.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                ++net;
            }
            else {
                --net;
            }
            // update tally by adding low character
            if ("aeiou".indexOf(input.charAt(i-window)) != -1) {
                --net;
            }
            else {
                ++net;
            }
        }
    }

    return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be decision for your task (for not too long input string):

```
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Created by smv on 19/09/16.
 */
public class MainTest {

    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1;
    }

    public int getVowelCount(String str) {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(isVowel(str.charAt(i))) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int getConsonantCount(String str) {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(!isVowel(str.charAt(i))) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Exception {
        String string = "aasdaasggsertcwevwertwe";
        int lengthOfString = string.length();
        String maxSub = "";
        int maxSubLength = 0;

        // find all substrings of given string
        for( int c = 0 ; c < lengthOfString ; c++ )
        {
            for( int i = 1 ; i <= lengthOfString - c ; i++ )
            {
                String sub = string.substring(c, c+i);

                // comparing count vowels and consonants 
                if (getVowelCount(sub) == getConsonantCount(sub)) {
                    if (sub.length() > maxSubLength) {
                        maxSub = sub;
                        maxSubLength = sub.length();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxSub);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the requirements are very vague here of course. It does not mention if numbers or other keys are included in the input. I assumed a starting index of zero since counts are equal at that point.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string = new String(scanner.next());
    int lengthOfString = string.length();
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int consCount = 0;
    int maxIndex = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Char: " + string.charAt(i));

        if(string.charAt(i) == 'u' || string.charAt(i) == 'e' || string.charAt(i) == 'i'
            || string.charAt(i) == 'o' || string.charAt(i) == 'a') 
        {
            vowelCount++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            consCount++;
        }

        if(vowelCount == consCount)
        {
            System.out.println("count equal with: " + string.substring(0, (i + 1)));
            maxIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }

    if(maxIndex > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Longest sub string with equal count of vowels and consonants is: " 
            + string.substring(0, maxIndex));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No substring existed with equal count of vowels and consonants.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote in C# (my bad, sorry), but I think you can get the idea:

```
public string Foo(string stg)
{   
    var result = "";
    var sum = 0;
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (var index = 0; index < stg.Length; index++)
    {
        if ("AEIOUaeiou".Contains((stg[index].ToString()))) { sum += 1; }
        else { sum -= 1; }

        if (sum == 0)
        {
            result = stg.Substring(0, index + 1);
        }

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(sum))
        {
            if (result.Length < index - dictionary[sum])
            {
                result = stg.Substring(dictionary[sum], index - dictionary[sum] + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(sum, index);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```